# Print out timestamp as number, not human readable

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need a command line that runs against psql and does:

```
psql database -c "select date_trunc('day', start) as date, avg(finish - start) as duration from things group by date order by date;"
```

But the problem is this gives me human readable output, aka:

```
    date         |    duration
---------------------+-----------------
 2010-01-11 00:00:00 | 00:24:13.826822
 2010-01-12 00:00:00 | 00:15:42.984878
 2010-01-13 00:00:00 | 00:15:37.117834
 2010-01-14 00:00:00 | 00:13:27.868552
 2010-01-15 00:00:00 | 00:09:16.018057
 2010-01-16 00:00:00 | 00:06:39.213929
```

What I want are unix timestamps in seconds (or milliseconds) as integers on both sides.  I've read documentation but can't figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

I read that you can do it with

```
SELECT date_part('epoch', now())
```

give unix timestamp

So in your case

```
SELECT date_part('epoch', date_trunc('day', start) as date), 
       date_part('epoch', avg(finish - start)) as duration 
FROM things 
GROUP by date 
ORDER by date;
```

See [Date and time functions and operations](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-datetime.html) in postgres